# Dynamically created selectors in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi I am trying to dynamically create a selector for jQuery instead of using a static one.  The problem is, it is not working predictably/consistently.

I created a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/Cc92f/

If you click run and click in each of the top radio buttons once, they work, but you cannot use the same buttons a second time.

If you click a top button, and then a bottom button, you can no longer click any of the buttons.

You may have to reload it a couple of times to see how different uses break it in different ways.

Thanks you for any and all help!

```
    $(".concattest").click(function(event)
    {
        var radioid=event.target.id.split("_");
        $('#r_2_'+radioid[2]).attr('checked', 'checked');
        event.preventDefault();
    });
```

Comment: What are you even trying to achieve with that code? I find it very confusing that clicking on the radio buttons doesn't select them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Use `.prop('checked',true)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr) instead of `.attr('checked','checked')`.

http://jsfiddle.net/5LWEk/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to:

1. When changing selection in the top row, change value of bottom row
   accordingly
2. When changing selection in the bottom row, select the last option in
   the top row

Then use `change` event and `prop()` function, here is the [<kbd>**demo**</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/n1k1ch/Cc92f/2/)